# Entity Framework 5 - Why is Entity State "Modified" after PropertyValue is set back to Original

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i use the EF5 and don't know why a entity has the state "modified" after i set the only changed PropertyValue of this entity back to the original value.

```
using (TestDbContext context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            string name = context.Person.First().Name;

            // count is 0
            int count = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);

            // Change Value
            context.Person.First().Name = "Test";

            // count is 1 
            count = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);

            // Revert Value
            context.Person.First().Name = name;


            context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            // count is 1 
            count = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
        }
```

Why? :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because Entity Framework only keeps track if the data got modified, not if it's different from it's original content.

We use a nifty method to reset the state to unmodified when the entity is unchanged:

```
    public static void CheckIfModified(EntityObject entity, ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (entity.EntityState == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            ObjectStateEntry state = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
            DbDataRecord orig = state.OriginalValues;
            CurrentValueRecord curr = state.CurrentValues;

            bool changed = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < orig.FieldCount && !changed; ++i)
            {
                object origValue = orig.GetValue(i);
                object curValue = curr.GetValue(i);
                if (!origValue.Equals(curValue) && (!(origValue is byte[]) || !((byte[])origValue).SequenceEqual((byte[])curValue)))
                {
                    changed = true;
                }
            }

            if (!changed)
            {
                state.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that this method is for EF 4.0, not for the newer versions with DbContext. But it is no problem to rewrite it to use EF 4.1+, I have done this myself already but I can't find the code right now.

Comment: Once you have `changed = true;` you can `break` from the loop, to not waste cycles.

Comment: Good point, thank you. :) I'll add that to our implementation.

Comment: Little bit mysterious to put it into loop's condition. :) On a first sight I would miss it.

Comment: Oh.. true.. I forgot that too. Probably still comes from my school time where they always told us: Break is evil!

Comment: In addition to the byte[] comparison case, you should check for string because 99% of the time you won't want to consider null and string.Empty a change.

Comment: I don't get what is evil here, breaking from a loop when it doesn't need to continue is very well suited in this situation too. And I think it's commonly used too.

Answer (score 6):

Thx for the hint :)

here is my EF5 (DbContext) Solution. I call this method for every DbEnityEntry that i get from ChangeTracker.Entries()

```
    private void CheckIfDifferent(DbEntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry.State != EntityState.Modified) 
            return;

        if (entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Any(propertyName => !entry.OriginalValues[propertyName].Equals(entry.CurrentValues[propertyName])))
            return;

       (this.dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity).ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
    }
```

Comment: Please note that your version is faulty. When comparing byte arrays (blobs, rowversion) you don't have to use the .Equals() method. Please check my version again. And if my answer helped you, you might mark it as an answer. :) Also use ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.dbContext) instead of your version. This will give you a minor speed optimization, but more important: It will throw a proper exception when dbContext is not an IObjectContextAdapter, instead of a NullReferenceException (unlikely, but I rather program defensive).

Comment: I believe that `entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Any(propertyName => !entry.OriginalValues[propertyName].Equals(entry.CurrentValues[propertyName]))` will throw an error if any OriginalValue is null. There should be a test for OriginalValue is null and CurrentValue is not null to cover the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Building on User1481065's answer, to overcome the possibility of an exception if any of `OriginalValues` is null, try the below. I've assumed a context that may contain more than one entity that may have updates (which may not necessarily be actual changes in value).

```
_dirty = False
Dim oChanges As IEnumerable(Of DbEntityEntry(Of CsSetting)) = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries(Of CsSetting)().Where(Function(r) r.State <> EntityState.Unchanged)
For Each c As DbEntityEntry(Of CsSetting) In oChanges
    _dirty = c.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Any(Function(n) (c.OriginalValues(n) Is Nothing And c.CurrentValues(n) IsNot Nothing) OrElse (c.OriginalValues(n) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not c.OriginalValues(n).Equals(c.CurrentValues(n))))
    If _dirty Then Exit For
Next c
Return _dirty
```

You may not need the loop and therefore the presetting of `_dirty`.