# Does entity framework compare assigned values with original to determine IsModified flag?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, updates

If I load entity object and then assign one of properties to the same value as it had before, does framework detect changes or it would set IsModified flag to true anyway ?

This is how generated code for field Name looks like:

```
OnNameChanging(value);
ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
_Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
OnNameChanged();
```

I don't know which of those events set IsModified flag for that field and for the whole entity.

Comment: Just try, you'll find out quick enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your context only keeps track if your data got modified, not if it's different.

You can do a check like this:

```
  private void CheckIfDifferent(DbEntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry.State != EntityState.Modified) 
            return;

        if (entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Any(propertyName => !entry.OriginalValues[propertyName].Equals(entry.CurrentValues[propertyName])))
            return;

       (this.dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity).ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
    }
```

source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515869/1339087

Comment: It's not clear to me what "only if data got modified, not if it's different" means. Could you clarify.

Comment: only if data got modified means that if the value changed at all, even back to its original value :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like things are different now (EF6).  I was researching this to see if I needed to use an if statement when setting property values to see if the "new value" is different.  I tested with the following and the entity is not marked as modified:

```
var things = dbContext.Things.AsQueryable();
var thing = things.First();
string name = thing.Name;
thing.Name = name;
var entry = dbContext.Entry(thing);
var state = entry.State;
int count = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
var modified = entry.Property(x => x.Name).IsModified;
```

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/property-values#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20property%20value%20like%20this%20will%20only%20mark%20the%20property%20as%20modified%20if%20the%20new%20value%20is%20different%20from%20the%20old%20value.) to prove this for EF6.

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20EF%20Core%20creates%20a%20snapshot%20of%20every%20entity%27s%20property%20values%20when%20it%20is%20first%20tracked%20by%20a%20DbContext%20instance.%20The%20values%20stored%20in%20this%20snapshot%20are%20then%20compared%20against%20the%20current%20values%20of%20the%20entity%20in%20order%20to%20determine%20which%20property%20values%20have%20changed.) to prove this for EF Core.