# How to detect changes in 1 entity framework object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a list of entities and when some entities change I just perform the following:

```
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

and all modifications are saved.

but now I have to perform some business logic when certain entities are changed (and only for the ones that are changed) and need to find those changed entities. But I can't seem to be able to do this.

I've come across this post: [Entity Framework 5 - Why is Entity State "Modified" after PropertyValue is set back to Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515190/entity-framework-5-why-is-entity-state-modified-after-propertyvalue-is-set-b)

where someone checks the `.EntityState` property ....

But my entity does not have this property.

As a last resort I could use `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the level of my model, but would be nice if EF5 would let me know the state of that entity.

Comment: Are you using entities or POCOs? By their very nature POCOs won't have a state unless you create/set a property to maintain a state. However, you can setup your code so that your POCOs become proxies in which case they will have state and when you link becomes relevant. We need more information to help further. In addition if you have layered architecture be aware that passing proxy/entities across boundaries can become problematic when they are detached / serialised etc.

Comment: Well, ... all Model classes + mappings are created manually .. not sure if it's called poco, will have to look it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check the state of an entity use the following:

```
DbEntityEntry entry = Context.Entry(entity); //where Context is DbContext or derived

// entry.State is available here
```